# Why can a description be used as a name here?

Tags: usage, nouns

Usually '3 apples' or 'one person' or 'a man' are used as description phrases, like: 'I am one man', how come we use phrases (dealing with cost) like the following:

> Three dollars is the price

Why are we able to discuss 'three dollars' as if it is some kind of thing being named, I can say 'three men walk into the bar but then I am describing them'.

Comment: The sentence refers to a sum of $3, not three individual dollars like three individual men.

Comment: Do you have a problem with "He gave me three dollars"?

Comment: @StuartF no because it's describing what he gave me, where as 'three dollars is the price' sounds like 'three dollars' refers to a particular thing that is the price, like 'the man over there is the king'.

Answer (score 1):

The normal, unmarked expression would be "The price is three dollars." The speaker and the listener have implicitly agreed that a price exists and the speaker is informing the listener of what that price *is*.

But consider the following exchange.

> How much is this orange.
>
> Three dollars.
>
> Three dollars! Are you kidding me? For one orange??  Three dollars is a rip-off.
>
> Well, three dollars is the price.  You can pay it or you can leave.

After the first exchange, both speaker have agreed that "three dollars" is the amount of money under discussion, and the second speaker is informing the first that "three dollar" is the price that he charges for an orange.

So you are right, "Three dollars" is the thing being named, the thing under discussion, and the difference of opinion is whether it is the fair price of an orange, or a rip-off.

This is quite normal, and may be used for emphasis or just because it is "logical".

> Three dollars is a fair price to pay for oranges like this, they are very sweet and juicy.

Comment: My issue with that is:  if 'three dollars' is the name of an amount, but 'three men' describes people' where as to say 'three men' is an amount and then use it as an 'amount' thing that can be discussed you could say 'the amount is three men' which doesn't feel right at all.

Comment: There's no rule that says that "amounts" can't be the subject in a sentence.  You can discuss an amount.  If you like it is "Three dollars of money" (but the of money is nearly always dropped).  You will allow "Three kg of flour is enough for a wedding cake."  And you should allow "How much flour for the wedding cake?" / "Three kilograms is enough" when the context means that we understand "3kg" to mean "3kg of flour".  There is no problem with an amount being the subject of a sentence.

Comment: In all cases, we are using the phrase to describe something? So it is a descriptive phrase for saying 'I want the flour you get to be four kilogrammes'? But can we, from context use '3 apples is an amount' like 'green is a colour' ? In 'three men enter the bar' they can be subjects but we are kind of describing, where in my 'green' example, the other is kind of 'naming' but '3 men' isn't a kind of name is it? Yet '3 dollars is the price' uses it lke that. I apologise in my language there is a way that kind of differentiates these.

Comment: I am confused by your use of the word "name" I think you mean "noun".   In English there is no problem with " Three dollars is the price" or "Three kilograms is enough" and so on.  Dollar is a noun and can be the subject of a sentence.

Comment: I mean a word (or phrase) that refers to some thing in a way it becomes one of the things under discussion in an obvious way, for example: 'Dollar' is a one, 'green' is another but 'three dollars' *describes* something as opposed to 'Dollar', 'green', or 'my neighbour across the road', like 'three boxes in my room' is not referring to some thing called 'three boxes' but of a group of things, yet as I say 'the price is three dollars' is like: 'I am john' except 'three dollars' doesnt work like 'I' or 'John'.

Comment: I don't think this is a significant grammar point in English.  Noun phrases can be subject.  You can form the subject of a sentence with "A dollar" or "The green", or "Three dollars" or "My neighbour across the road" or "The three boxes in my room".  These are all grammatically correct noun phrases and all could be the subject of a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

The subject of a sentence whose main verb is "*is*" (or another form of "To be") need not be a name, and is not in this case. Such a subject is often a descriptive phrase. Some examples might be:

> - The red brick building on 24th street **is** the place where I work.
> - George Higgins's last novel **was** *Sandra Nicols Found Dead*.
> - The period from 30 to 60 **is** often considered to constitute "middle age".
> - The phrase "middle of the night" **is** not an exact time.
> - Impressionist paintings **were** very popular in the late 19th- and early 20th centuries.

Of course in many other cases the subject consists of a name, but there is no rule that requires a name as the subject of "to be".

Comment: In a sentence that starts "Three men walk into a bar and..."  the  noun phrase "three men" is the subject of the verb "walk" This is a very common construction. I am not sur what you mean by "denoting phrase". That is not a term I have encountered. "men" is a noun, and "three" is an adjective indicating how many men there are. Together these words form a noun phrase, which is very commonly used as a subject. Many noun phrases are descriptive, and can still be used as subjects. Prices are not usually expressed in "men" unless one is speaking of a culture that practices slavery.

Comment: that was a mistake by me, sorry I meant 'three dollars'. Why is 'three men' both a noun phrase to indicate men, then  'three dollars 'noun phrase to indicate price, so we are 'describing' the price then as a sort of collection of these abstract things we call dollars?